# Constraintlayout in linearLayout different preview between emulator and IDE?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement a `ContstraintLayout` in my code, but the problem is why there is different when I run it on the emulator and in the IDE? 
for the info, I put `ConstraintLayout` in `LinearLayout` Vertical.
and here my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="navotera.syasep.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/topBorder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:foregroundGravity="right"
                android:src="@mipmap/profile"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.99"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
                android:paddingLeft="270dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/nama"
                    android:text="Hendra" />

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_big"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/nim"
                    android:text="nim" />

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:foregroundGravity="right">

                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_bigger"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/semester"
                        android:text="7"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="184dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tsemester" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="IPK"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                        android:layout_width="88dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tipk"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tsemester"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ipk" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/ipk"
                        android:text="3.99"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_bigger"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/semester"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Semester"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
                        android:layout_width="94dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tsemester"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="156dp" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:text="Jadwal / Kehadiran"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="13dp"
            android:id="@+id/tkehadiran"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

thanks for any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: your LinearLayout does not has orientation property set

Answer (score 2):

if using ConstraintLayout, then put all the views as a direct child of the ConstraintLayout, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2" app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
<RadioButton
    android:text="RadioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="376dp"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"/>
<QuickContactBadge
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@mipmap/star_empty"
    android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Comment: im following your suggestion to make constraint layout as root layout. 
can u explain this hehe...

https://ibb.co/iTb2Tv

Comment: i am also new to this constraintlayout thing, only checked it once or twice, but in every case i first the layout with relativelayout and linearlayout and then converted them to constraintlayout

Comment: when i put the textview behind that linearlayout. you know ? that textview become invisible ?? that strange ? :D

Comment: i want to share that when any component widget in constraintlayout not being connected it would make overlap or not showed as supposed.

Comment: in that case my android studio (2.3) shows an error message stating that constraints are not set and your view will move to left during runtime

Answer (score 0):

Because the emulator is Nexus_5_API_21 but your preview is displaying on a Nexus_4_API_25 screen
Just change the preview to the appropriate screen

Comment: why it happen, does it mean when i use contstraint_layout it would make different view on different device ? 

does it mean constraint_layout is not stable in production used ? 

how about google statement that saying that this layout is support since https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html API level 9  ?